Turning a column of a 2D array into an array
I have a jagged array here, and I want to fetch the column of this array of arrays, and make the column into another array:
var array = [
    [0, 1, z, 0],
    [1, 0, s, 1],
    [0, 1, x, 0],
    [1, 0, a, 1],
];

So that the new array is:
var expectedOutput = [z, s, x, a];

How would I go about that?

Or as a function, getColumn


var array = [
  [0, 1, 'z', 0],
  [1, 0, 's', 1],
  [0, 1, 'x', 0],
  [1, 0, 'a', 1],
];


function getColumn(arr, index) {
  return arr.map(function(row) {
    return row[index]
  })
}

// or one liner:
var getColumn = (arr, index) => arr.map(row => row[index])

console.log(getColumn(array, 2))




Do you have a ES5 version? This one uses a arrow function

yes, i wrote both versions

You can use the .map function in JS for this and extract the 2nd value of each array into a new array.
var expectedOutput = array.map(item => item[2]);
The .map function works a bit like a for loop where it puts each entry into a function and returns a value.
